# Use Single Shortcut Key to Close Windows

Tags: macos, automator, shortcut, automation, keybindings

Some windows can be closed with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> while others require the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. How do you create a single key shortcut (maybe with <kbd>caps lock</kbd>?) that can close both types? A built-in solution in Mojave and Catalina is preferred, but using a free reputable third party utility would be OK.

Comment: Cmd/W closes windows, Esc closes dialogs. The two are not the same.

Comment: I"m looking for something (AppleScript, Automator, Karabiner?) that can detect whether it's a window or dialog to send the correct sequence.